# Error while Running a WebDriver using Python script

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I had a problem running executing a Webdriver using a script in python using the library selenium. I have posted the sample code scenarios as well as the corresponding error thrown while executing.

Code Scenario:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Error Scenario:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Kaushik/Desktop/IMC DEVELOPER TEST/Sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 60, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 83, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env).communicate()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

I coudnt understand the Error thrown. I just need to use the selenium library to retrieve a dynamic data from a website using a python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, it works fine for me.

Do you have firefox installed? if not, you can use a different browser. for example:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie
```

or

```
driver = webdriver.Opera
```